# The Buffer dont convert to base64 correctly when i am getting it from postgreSQL DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, buffer, bufferedimage

i am uploading image in avif o png or jpeg format, then sending that file to BE as Buffer and saving into postgreSQL DB .  file format changed
When I uploaded an image via input it was in avif format
After I converted it to a buffer and then to base64, the format changed to txt
the problem is this

```
            <Form.Item className={styles.formItem} name="exampleOne">
              <Upload
                accept=".avif"
                beforeUpload={(file: File) =>
                  handleImageUpload(file, "imageOne")
                }
              >
                <Button
                  text="Upload Example Image 1"
                  icon={<Upl
```

type here

```
oadOutlined />}
                />
                {images.imageOne && (
                  <img
                    src={images.imageOne}
                    alt="Uploaded"
                    className={styles.uploadedImage}
                  />
                )}
              </Upload>
            </Form.Item>
```

```
  const handleCreateNavBar = async (values: FormValues) => {
    const newNavBar = {
      isArchived: !!archivedCheckbox,
      name: {
        en: values.nameEn,
        ru: values.nameRu,
        arm: values.nameArm,
      },
      type: values.type,
      exampleOne: convertToBuffer(values.exampleOne.file),
      exampleTwo: convertToBuffer(values.exampleTwo.file),
      exampleThree: convertToBuffer(values.exampleThree.file),
      exampleFour: convertToBuffer(values.exampleFour.file),
    };

    try {
      const { navBar } = await createNavBar(newNavBar);
```

```
export const convertToBuffer = (file: any): Buffer => {
  const buffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(file)); 
  return buffer;
};
```

```
  {
    title: "Image 1",
    dataIndex: "exampleOne",
    width: 200,
    render: async (_: any, record: any) => {
      return (
        <img
          src={`data:image/avif;base64,${Buffer.from(
            record.exampleOne
          ).toString("base64")}`}
          alt="Example One"
        />
      );
    },
```

@Column("bytea", {
nullable: true,
})
exampleOne!: Buffer;

i have tried to convert buffer to base64 and when it hasnt worked into img component i have tryed to decode that base64 int online compiler and i have seen there file format changed
When I uploaded an image via input it was in avif format
After I converted it to a buffer and then to base64, the format changed to txt
the problem is this